# Print output to Excel file

Tags: pandas, export

I am connecting `LDAP` to fetch members of an AD group , i am successfully able to pull the membership of multiple AD group and print it in the `python` console.  How do i export the output to excel or `CSV` file now

```
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')
my output is in df 

df.to_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')
```

I am connecting `LDAP` to fetch members of an AD group , i am successfully able to pull the membership of multiple AD group and print it in the python console.  How do i export the output to excel or CSV file now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have the dataframe, df.

`filename = output.csv
df.to_csv(filename, index = False)`

The **to_csv** function of Panda's Dataframe would save the Dataframe as a CSV. The file would be found in the folder that contains the Python file and would be named as output.csv

Hope it helps :)

Comment: actually my print output looks something like below like CN = Groupname and its OU and their members